# n-simplex volume and triangle.

Tags: volume, simplex

For $n\in N$ let $\sum_n(1)$ be the standard-simplex. Let there be a point $b\in R^n$ and a basis {$a_1,...,a_n$} of $R^n$. The $n-simplex$ set up in this point b by the basis is the set 
\begin{equation*}
S_n(b;a_1,...,a_n):=\{b+\sum_{k=1}^nx_ka_k|(x_1,...,x_n)\in \sum_n(1)\}. 
\end{equation*}
1.1.: Show that
\begin{equation*}
v_n(S_n(b;a_1,...,a_n))=\frac{|det(a_1,...,a_n)|}{n!}. 
\end{equation*}
1.2.: $z_0,z_1,z_2\in C$ are the vertices of a triangle $\Delta$ in the complex plane. Show that the area is 
\begin{equation*}
F=\frac{1}{2}|Im(\overline{(z_1-z_0)}(z_2-z_0))|. 
\end{equation*}

My ideas so far:

1.1: I know that the general formula for $v_n$ of an $n-simplex$ is $\frac{a^n}{n!}$, but I can't see how the determinant plays a role in here.

1.2.: [image]

I tried to put in general coordinates for $z_0,z_1,z_1$ and trying to see if I can find something out of it. So, for $z_i=a_i+ib_i$ I get  $\frac{1}{2}(-b_1+b_0)(b_2-b_0)$ and can't seem to see a connection to the genreal way of trying to find the area of a triangle since this only has values in the y-coordinate (in this case the $C$-axis).

Would like if someone had some hints about these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think to determinant as to an operator that gives you the hyper-volume of ${\{\overrightarrow a_1, \overrightarrow a_2, \dots, \overrightarrow a_n}\}$ basis compared to hyper-volume of standard basis ${\{\overrightarrow e_1, \overrightarrow e_2, \dots, \overrightarrow e_n}\} $, which is 1 because product of othogonal vectors of length 1. 
In fact you are applying a transformation, call it $\phi$, to pass from ${\{\overrightarrow e_1, \overrightarrow e_2, \dots, \overrightarrow e_n}\}$ basis to ${\{\overrightarrow a_1, \overrightarrow a_2, \dots, \overrightarrow a_n}\}$ basis and the determinant says the scaling factor the hyper-volume generated of vectors done by $\phi$.

In the same way $S_n{(\overrightarrow b; \overrightarrow a_1, \overrightarrow a_2, \dots, \overrightarrow a_n)}$ is the final risult of $\phi$ applied on $S_n({\overrightarrow e_1, \overrightarrow e_2, \dots, \overrightarrow e_n})$.

About the second question:
call $a = z_1-z_0$ and $b = z_2-z_0$.
Expanding them in real and imaginary parts, calculate $F$
$$
\begin{align}
F &= \frac{1}{2} |Im( (\overline{z_1-z_0}) (z_2-z_0) )| \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} |Im( \bar a b )| \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} |Im( (a_r - i a_i) (b_r + i b_i) )| \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} |Im( a_rb_r + ia_rb_i - ia_ib_r + a_ib_i )|
\end{align}
$$
The imaginary part here is the determinant of $a$ and $b$ thought as vectors of components $a=(a_r, a_i)$, $b=(b_r, b_i)$.

Comment: Okay, I can see that the determinant shows the volume of $(a_1,...,a_n)$, but I can't see how it stays the same with $b$ included. Because $b$ is a point made out of the basis, making $(b,a_1,...,a_n)$ not orthogonal anymore. 


About 1.2.: Maybe I never read about it, but why is the determiant the area of a triangle ( half of it to be more precise ).

Comment: $b$ is a translation vector (see $S_n(\dots)$ definition) and isn't included in the basis $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ for the construction of the n-simplex; in other words, if you translate a figure by a vector, its n-volume doesn't change. About 1.2) Consider generic vectors $a$, $b$ centered in $O=(0,0)$, they are 2 sides of a triangle, they are also 2 non-parallel sides of a parallelogram. The area of parallelogram is the determinant of matrix made of column vectors $a$ and $b$, so the area of the triangle is half cutting on diagonal of the parallellogram.

Comment: Oh. I think now I get your approach to this. I will try this out once I'm home. 

Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer is satisfiyng, then put the tick near it to accept it. Please, do it also for the answers of your previous questions.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother again. I tried to write the proof down and I'm kind of stuck at this point: The volume of an $n-simplex$ is $\frac{a^n}{n!}$ and $det(a_1,...,a_n)$ is the scaling factor of the hyper volume of the standard basis, which is 1, and therefore the determinant is the volume. But how do I include the $n!$ into it? Or is it that $a^n=det(a_1,...,a_n)$?

Comment: $|a_1 \dots a_n| = det(a_1, ... a_n)$ is the volume of the n-dimensional parallelipiped formed by $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$. You get $\frac{det(a_1, ... a_n)}{n!}$ because you are cutting out the n-symplex from it. An idea of dimonstration could be getting the volume from standard basis symplex by integrating on each vector, the result would be $\frac{1}{n!}$, then transform it to the needed simplex.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Didn't think of it as an parallelipiped before.